# How do I fix "Cannot be applied to" errors?

Tags: java

I am kind of a rookie to Java, especially Object-Oriented programming in Java, and I keep getting this error that is driving my crazy.

Here is a section of my Employee superclass:

```
public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String socialSecurityNumber) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;
}
private final String firstName;
private final String lastName;
private final String socialSecurityNumber;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public String getSocialSecurityNumber() {
    return socialSecurityNumber;
}
```

and the subclass CommissionEmployee:

```
public CommissionEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, 
String socialSecurityNumber, double grossSales, 
double commissionRate)
{
  this.firstName = firstName;                                    
  this.lastName = lastName;                                    
  this.socialSecurityNumber = socialSecurityNumber;         
  this.grossSales = grossSales;
  this.commissionRate = commissionRate;
}
```

And the same error that I get is:

```
constructor Employee in class Employee cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,String,String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

What exactly does this mean, what causes it, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `CommissionEmployee` is a subclass of `Employee`, Java requires that a constructor of `Employee` is called when constructing a `CommissionEmployee`. By default, this is a call to the no-argument constructor `Employee()`, which in your case does not exist.

You have two options:

- Call the superclass constructor that already exists:

  ```
  public CommissionEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, 
  String socialSecurityNumber, double grossSales, 
  double commissionRate)
  {
    super(firstName, lastName, socialSecuityNumber);  
    this.grossSales = grossSales;
    this.commissionRate = commissionRate;
  }
  ```
- Create a no-arg superclass constructor and set the first/last name and SSN in the subclass constructor (less ideal). The superclass (Employee) constructor is protected so it can't be called except by subclasses, and is as follows:

  ```
  protected Employee() {}
  ```